# Can I use a removable hard drive from a normal Xbox 360 on a slim model?

Tags: xbox-360

Can I use a removable hard drive from a Xbox 360 on a Xbox 360 slim?

Comment: How do you plan on "using" it? A 360 hard drive physically can't fit in a slim, unless you're asking *how* you might be able to do that?

Comment: @Ben Presumably using an adapter like the one you posted. The problem is that "is there an adapter for this hard drive" gets locked as a hardware recommendation so OP had to be vague.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do anything without one of these:

[image]

This is a hard drive transfer cable for the Xbox 360 (it works with all models).

This will also allow you to transfer all of your content from the 360 hard drive to your 360S hard drive. However, you can effectively use this as a USB connection cable *if necessary*. In the case when you might not have a hard drive in your 360S, or there is not enough space, you can still access the data on your original hard drive without needing to transfer it.